# There is something wrong with the if condition

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

The below code is part of a program. When the string s is passed as "one one" then in the first iteration, the value of the variable word is getting set to one but still, program is not getting inside the if statement. Please help.

```
for (String word : s.split(" ")) {

        if (word == "one") {

            if (d == 2) {
                r = s.concat("11");
                d = 0;
            }

            else if (t == 3) {
                r = s.concat("111");
                t = 0;
            }

            else {
                r = s.concat("1");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: How about a real [mcve] instead of this? You know, something that compiles when copypasted into an online IDE.

Comment: you are comparing your Strings as if you're using JavaScript. Java isn't JavaScript

Comment: Don't use double-equals to compare strings in Java.   The answer you will get is usually not what you want.  Use `.equals()` instead, as in `word.equals("one")`